# ChakraCore for the Apple Silicon

Tags: .net, macos, arm64, apple-silicon, chakracore

Did somebody solve the problem with ChakraCore and the new Apple Silicon chip?

```
Engine name: ChakraCoreJsEngine
Engine version: Nov 11, 2021
Category: Engine load error
Description: Most likely it happened, because the 'libChakraCore.dylib' assembly or one of its dependencies was not found. There is no JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.Native.osx-* package for the arm64 processor architecture. You can build the 'libChakraCore.dylib' assembly for the current processor architecture by using following instructions from official repository - https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/wiki/Building-ChakraCore#os-x. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'ChakraCore' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libChakraCore, 0x0001): tried: 'libChakraCore' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibChakraCore' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libChakraCore' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libChakraCore' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libChakraCore' (not a file), '/usr/lib/libChakraCore' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
   at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.JsRt.NativeMethods.JsCreateRuntime(JsRuntimeAttributes attributes, JsThreadServiceCallback threadService, JsRuntime& runtime)
   at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.JsRt.JsRuntime.Create(JsRuntimeAttributes attributes, JsThreadServiceCallback threadServiceCallback)
   at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.ChakraCoreJsEngine.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.ScriptDispatcher.ScriptTaskWithoutResult.Run()
```

Wiki was updated 5 years ago. On [www.nuget.org](http://www.nuget.org) also no package for mac-arm64 exists.
Any suggestions, please?